# React/Redux: Action dispatched, state not updating

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I'm extremely new to Redux (this is my first project using it) and I've run into a bit of a roadblock.

What I have here is a simple scenario in which an input value changes, updating the Redux store onChange. Here's a look at my code:

**The component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { setSuperhero } from '../actions/setSuperhero'

const SearchField = (props) => (
  <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <form className="form-inline">
      <div className="form-group mb-0">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="superhero"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Thor, Iron Man, etc."
          onChange={(e) => {
            props.dispatch(setSuperhero(e.target.value));
          }}></input>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-light ml-2">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
)

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    superhero: state.superhero.name
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchField);
```

**The action:**

```
import * as types from '../types';

export const setSuperhero = name => dispatch => (
  dispatch({
    type: types.SET_SUPERHERO,
    payload: name
  })
)
```

**The types:**

```
export const SET_SUPERHERO = "SET_SUPERHERO";
```

**The reducer:**

```
import * as types from '../types'

const superheroReducer = (state = {name: 'Thor'}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.SET_SUPERHERO: {
      return {
        ...state,
        name: action.payload
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default superheroReducer
```

Logger indicates that the action is sent, the state just doesn't update with the value provided. I've tried looking at immutability. I've tried making sure my Provider is set up properly (it does). I've used and deleted 'mapDispatchToProps' about 100 times. I've looked through every recommended question on this board for an answer and still come I'm coming up empty. For whatever reason, this stupid thing just won't update.

Any help at all would be immensely appreciated.

**EDIT: As requested, here's the code for my root reducer:**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import uiReducer from './uiReducer';
import superheroReducer from './superheroReducer';
import heroInfoReducer from './heroInfoReducer';
import comicsReducer from './comicsReducer';
import seriesReducer from './seriesReducer';
import eventsReducer from './eventsReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  ui: uiReducer,
  superhero: superheroReducer,
  heroInfo: heroInfoReducer,
  comics: comicsReducer,
  series: seriesReducer,
  events: eventsReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

EDIT: Quick addendum on accepted answer: was calling 'thunk' AND 'promise' in my 'applyMiddleware' call. Removing 'promise' fixed the issue, but ultimately the problem was that I was passing in a function to my dispatch call. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Which state doesn't update?  You're passing `superhero` prop to `SearchField`, so you can access it with `props.superhero`. Can you please try to `console.log(props)` in `SearchField` and start typing in the input? What's the log?

Comment: Also can you please show us how you register the reducer?

Comment: @JordanEnev Added the reducer registry. I also console.logged my reducer and it doesn't appear to be firing.

Comment: Oh I see what's happening. You're returning function in your action. Dispatch expects an object.

Comment: That was the trick! I had thunk installed, but having both 'thunk' and 'promise' in my 'applyMiddleware' call was causing some kind of roadblock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here everything looks correct except

1. `setSuperhero` action is returning a function which is incorrect. It should return a plain object. Quoting from the [redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions)

> Actions are plain JavaScript objects. Actions must have a type property that indicates the type of action being performed.

So you need to change

```
export const setSuperhero = name => dispatch => (
  dispatch({
    type: types.SET_SUPERHERO,
    payload: name
  })
)
```

to

```
export const setSuperhero = name => ({
  type: types.SET_SUPERHERO,
  payload: name
});
```

2. You have not included the `createStore` part in the question. So if you want to access the subtree of state then you must register reducer at that tree using the [`combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) e.g. Here you want to access your state value at `state.superhero`. So you must register your reducer as such

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import reducers from "./reducer";

const store = createStore(combineReducers({ superhero: reducers }));

export default store;
```

Now you can access it as `state.superhero`. If you don't want to use the `combineReducers` and just register a single reducer as

```
const store = createStore(reducers)
```

then the superhero name data will be available under `state.name` and not the `state.superhero.name`.

Here is the working codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/n445j386xp

**Update:** 
As you have included the `createStore` part in the question now, The problem is with your action. It must return a plain object, not a function. Rest looks good.

Hope, it helps :)

Comment: You and Jordan Enev hit the nail on the head. I was returning a function instead of a plain object, so I needed thunk middleware. I don't know what the conflict was, but it turns out I had both 'thunk' and 'promise' in my 'applyMiddleware' call and removing 'promise' fixed the problem!

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped :)